# Create disabled binding in attribute directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to create a really simple character counter directive that I can just drop an attribute on any `textarea` or `input` and get an easy way to have the `input/textarea` obey angulars `ng-maxlength` and would be able to prevent typing past that point and append a simple span element after the `input/textarea` that would have a character count down.

What I'm now trying to figure out is how I can bind the disabled state of the `input/textarea` to be disabled once the max character count has been reached

```
angular.module('bidrAdminApp')
  .directive('characterCounter', function ($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        characterCount: '=ngModel',
        maxLength: '=ngMaxlength'
      },
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log(attrs);
        var el = '<i>{{maxLength - characterCount.length}}</i>';
        el = $compile(el)(scope);
        $(element).after(el);
      }
    };
  });
```

And the template is pretty straight forward so far

Comment: The `ng-` prefix is reserved for AngularJS core directives. Specifically `ng-model` is reserved for directives that use the [NgModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController). User created directives should use another prefix. For more information, see [AngularJS Wiki -- Best Practices](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Best-Practices).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend to register any `$watcher`. In your case a simple event listener would suffice:

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .directive('myMaxCount', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {
      var max = attr.myMaxCount;
      
      element.on('keydown', keydownHandler);
      scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
        element.off('keydown', keydownHandler);
      });      
      
      function keydownHandler (e) {
        if(e.target.value.length + 1 > max) {
          e.preventDefault();
        }
      }
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <input type="text" my-max-count="5"/>
</div>
```

This is way do not polute your `$digest` cycle :)
Note that you have to deregister the listener in order to prevent memory leaks.

Comment: In the end this one actually ended up working and I like the fact it doesn't have as much overhead.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a watcher to the model and then do your logic there...

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive('characterCounter', function($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        characterCount: '=ngModel',
        maxLength: '=ngMaxLength'
      },
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
        var el = '<i>{{maxLength - characterCount.length}}</i>';
        el = $compile(el)(scope);
        $(element).after(el);
        $(element).attr('max', scope.maxLength);
        /*
        scope.$watch('characterCount', function(newVal, oldVal) {
          if(!newVal) return;
          
          if(newVal.length >= scope.maxLength) {
            $(element).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
          } else {
            $(element).removeAttr('disabled');
          }
        })*/

        // if you don't want the disabled attribute:

        scope.$watch('characterCount', function(newVal, oldVal) {
          if (!newVal) return;

          if (newVal.length > scope.maxLength) {
            scope.characterCount = oldVal;
          }
        })
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  
  <label>With input</label> <br/>
  <input type="text" character-counter ng-model="model" ng-max-length="10"/>
  <br/><br/>
  
  <label>With textArea</label><br/>
  <textarea character-counter ng-model="textArea" ng-max-length="10">
  
  </textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a new `scope.$watch` function which will watch the `characterCount` value and run a function when it changes.  In that case, it will trim the length to be `maxLength` which will work for both typing and copying/pasting into the text field.  It will also work if you manually set the value in a controller using a value that is longer than `maxLength`.

```
angular.module('bidrAdminApp')
  .directive('characterCounter', function ($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        characterCount: '=ngModel',
        maxLength: '=ngMaxlength'
      },
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log(attrs);
        var el = '<i>{{maxLength - characterCount.length}}</i>';
        el = $compile(el)(scope);
        $(element).after(el);

        scope.$watch('characterCount', function(newVal, oldVal) {
            scope.characterCount = scope.characterCount.substr(0, scope.maxLength);
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of answers already, but I think it is better to not use any Jquery in angular directive, because it makes it hard to test. here is an solution using $watch to do the exact same job.

```js
app = angular.module("bidrAdminApp", [])
  .directive('characterCounter', function($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        characterCount: '=ngModel',
        lengthLimit: '=lengthLimit'
      },
      link: function(scope, ele, attrs) {
        scope.$parent.count = attrs.lengthLimit;
        scope.$watch("characterCount", function(newvalue, oldvalue) {
          if (newvalue) {
            scope.$parent.count = attrs.lengthLimit - newvalue.length;
            if (newvalue.length >= attrs.lengthLimit) {
              scope.$parent.disabled = true;
            }
          }
        })
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="bidrAdminApp">
  <input ng-model="test" length-limit="10" character-counter ng-disabled="disabled"><span>{{count}}</span>
</body>
```